# Python - WTForms Coerce to Object

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongoengine, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm using a `SelectMultipleField` in a WTForm class that gets values from MongoDB.The input needs to be coerced to handle these MongoDB object IDs or I get this error:

> Invalid choice(s): one or more data inputs could not be coerced

I have tried the following.

```
groups = SelectMultipleField("Groups: ", coerce=object)
```

but it doesn't doesn't work.

Here's what the HTML looks like (notice the object IDs used for `value`):

```
<select class="form-control" id="groups" multiple name="groups">
    <option value="53921416b45ba747082829f1">My Group</option>
    <option value="53921c1402b8754f85446e5a">ttt</option>
    <option value="53921cf602b8755019a9562e">Developers</option>
    <option value="53921de202b875518e449bad">sadf</option>
    <option value="53921fa902b87553366482cc">asdf</option>
</select>
```

What is the correct way to coerce the value (to handle object IDs)?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you just need to use `ObjectID()` from MongoDB. First, import `ObjectID`

```
from bson import ObjectID
```

Then modify your `coerce` parameter to

```
coerce=ObjectId
```